# Bootstrap multi-column dropdown does not change li class active

Tags: drop-down-menu, multiple-columns

I have some strange behaviour for the dropdown that I decided to transfer to multicolumn.

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
<li class='dropdown'>
  <a href='#ExtRep' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Extended reports <b class='caret'></b></a>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <ul class='multi-column-dropdown'>
          <li class='disabled' disabled>Server 1</li>
          <li class='divider'></li>
          <li><a href='#tabl1' data-toggle='tab'>Report 1</a></li>
          <li><a href='#tabl2' data-toggle='tab'>Report 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <ul class='multi-column-dropdown'>
          <li class='disabled' disabled>Server 2</li>
          <li class='divider'></li>
          <li><a href='#tabl3' data-toggle='tab'>Report 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <ul class='multi-column-dropdown'>
          <li class='disabled' disabled>Server 3</li>
          <li class='divider'></li>
          <li><a href='#tabl5' data-toggle='tab'>Report 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Here is the sample: https://jsfiddle.net/Meeshka/0fazzvdh/9

When selecting each line in dropdown for the first time all is working like a charm. But trying to return to report 3 or 5 I see that I can't do that. While inspecting the code I saw that although I switch to Report 1 or 2, the li element of previous report remains with class="active".

```
<li class='active'><a href='#tabl3' data-toggle='tab'>Report 3</a></li>
```

This happens only when I switch between reports in different columns.
Reports in the same drop-down column are working OK. 
If I add to each column at least 2 lines, I can manage to switch but not in 100% cases, behavior is unpredictable.

Like in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/Meeshka/0fazzvdh/1/

Is the only way to make it wor correctly is to manually trigger class attribute for the element when I switch to another one? 
Is it a bug at all or something I miss in the code?

Answer (score 0):

So far I guess there is no "correct" solution to the bug.
If somebody wants a ready and a very straight forwarded solution, here is how I solved it:

```js
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(event) {
          $(this).closest('div.row').find('li').each(function(){
            //console.log($(this).attr('class'));
            $(this).removeClass('active');
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Here's how it looks like in fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Meeshka/0fazzvdh/10/